# Pandas replace negative value with zero, in columns that match a regular expression

Tags: python, regex, pandas

The goal is to replace all negative values in only certain columns ("capped1" and "capped2" but not "signed") with zeros. The columns need to be selected by a regular expression. (actual df has >1000 columns with more complex names)

I came up with:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np
index = [1,2,3,4]
d = {'capped1': [1,0,-1,np.nan], 'capped2': [2,0,np.nan,-9999],'signed':[2,0,-3,np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=index)
df_right = df.filter(regex=("capped.*")).clip(lower=0)
df_left = df.drop(list(df_right.columns), 1)
df_out = df_left.merge(df_right,left_index=True,right_index=True,how="outer")
df_out
```

is there an better way to do this? My guess is that this can be replaced by one line instead of 3 where you replace the values in df directly.

Answer (score 5):

**Option 1**
Use [**`pd.DataFrame.update`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) with [**`pd.DataFrame.clip`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html)
This edits `df` in place

```
df.update(df.filter(regex="^capped.*$").clip(lower=0))
df

   capped1  capped2  signed
1      1.0      2.0     2.0
2      0.0      0.0     0.0
3      0.0      NaN    -3.0
4      NaN      0.0     NaN
```

---

**Option 2**
Use [**`pd.DataFrame.assign`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [**`np.maximum`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html)
This produces a copy and leaves `df` alone
I use `np.maximum` as variety.  I could've used `pd.DataFrame.clip`
Notice that I use `**` to unpack the dataframe that is returned by `np.maximum` as a dictionary.  It is equivalent to `**{c: s for c, s in d.iteritems()}` where `d` is the return value from `np.maximum`

```
df.assign(**np.maximum(df.filter(regex='^capped.*'), 0))

   capped1  capped2  signed
1      1.0      2.0     2.0
2      0.0      0.0     0.0
3      0.0      NaN    -3.0
4      NaN      0.0     NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get columns names and then apply function only in subset:

```
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('^capped.*')]
print (cols)
Index(['capped1', 'capped2'], dtype='object')

df[cols] = df[cols].clip(lower=0)
print (df)
   capped1  capped2  signed
1      1.0      2.0     2.0
2      0.0      0.0     0.0
3      0.0      NaN    -3.0
4      NaN      0.0     NaN
```

Similar solution:

```
m = df.columns.str.contains('^capped.*')
print (m)
[ True  True False]

df.loc[:, m] = df.loc[:, m].clip(lower=0)
print (df)
   capped1  capped2  signed
1      1.0      2.0     2.0
2      0.0      0.0     0.0
3      0.0      NaN    -3.0
4      NaN      0.0     NaN
```

Nice idea from comment by [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46685518/pandas-replace-negative-value-with-zero-in-columns-that-match-a-regular-express#comment80319105_46685583) - using `regex` is not necessary, here is possible use [`startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
 cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('capped')]
 m = df.columns.str.startswith('capped')
```

Comment: `capped*` matches `cappe` and then 0 or more `d` chars. I think OP meant either `capped\d+` or `capped.*`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Thank you for comment, `^capped\d+` is better?

Comment: I've often wondered why `df.filter` doesn't support `startswith` out of the box - you'd have thought it'd be a quite common way to filter certain columns...

Comment: @JonClements - I use your idea in answer, thank you again ;)

Comment: Oh... I wouldn't have bothered but if you are, then use `df.columns.str.startswith('capped')` which'll be better than using a regex unnecessarily... :)

Comment: `^capped\d+` just matches a string that starts with `capped` and then 1+ digits. I do not quite get the question, maybe `capped` is enough here.